# VSTAScriptingLib for SQL Server 2012

Tags: dll, ssis, sql-server-2012, ezapi

I'm attempting to build the [2012 version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2012/02/15/ezapi-updated-for-sql-server-2012.aspx) of [EzAPI for SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api.aspx).  I'm getting an assembly dependency error during the build:

> Error  1   Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' uses 'Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'  c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents\Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript.dll   EzAPI

Basically, I need the 11.0.0.0 version of VSTAScriptingLib, but it's not included in the SQL Server 2012 distribution (as far as I can tell).

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the EzAPI project, remove the existing reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib`

Then add it back in but you'll have to navigate to the actual location in the GAC to find it. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib.dll`

I'll see if that's something that should have been put "elsewhere" during the SQL Server install.

Comment: That did it...I had to add the directory to the project Reference Path as well as it kept trying to revert to the 10.0.0.0 version.