# ssis 2012 task ezapi

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012, ezapi

I'm trying to use the SSIS ezAPI library on SQL Server 2012 using VS 2010. I have been looking at the very helpful blog and examples by 
bill fellows and the examples that come with ezAPI. My end goal BTW is to auto generate simple validate flat fill input to ADO.net destinations that 
are automapped via VS 2010 application.

The problem that I am having is that in all examples , both ezAPI and @billinkc I am getting a task error that I cannot resolve. The error log that I 
have posted below comes from using bills replicate db example

> billfellows.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/replicate-tables-with-ssis-ezapi.html

.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException was unhandled
 HelpLink=#-1073614806
 Message=Cannot create a task from XML for task "", type ", {E3CFBEA8-1F48-40D8-91E1-   2DEDC1EDDD56}" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".

  Source={8975114C-7D4E-4B27-8FB9-1B7EC264B4A7}
  ErrorCode=-1073659898
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executables.Add(String moniker)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzExecutable.CreateExecutable()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzExecutable..ctor(EzContainer parent)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzSrcPackage`2..ctor()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzSrcDestPackage`4..ctor()
   at EzAPIRecipies.ReplicateOMatic..ctor(String sourceServer, String sourceDatabase, String table, String destinationServer, String destinationDatabase) in c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testauto6\testauto6\replicate1.cs:line 28
   at EzAPIRecipies.Driver.ReplicateTables() in c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testauto6\testauto6\Program.cs:line 41
   at EzAPIRecipies.Driver.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testauto6\testauto6\Program.cs:line 23
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       HelpLink=#-1073614806
       Message=Cannot create a task from XML for task "", type ", {E3CFBEA8-1F48-40D8-91E1-2DEDC1EDDD56}" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".

```
   Source={8975114C-7D4E-4B27-8FB9-1B7EC264B4A7}
   ErrorCode=-1073659898
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSExecutables100.Add(String bstrMoniker)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executables.Add(String moniker)
       InnerException:
```

My suspision is that since I am getting this error whenever I am trying to create a dataflow using bill or the ezAPI examples there is some issue with my particular build connfiguration.

When I reference the ezAPI.dll in my .net project, I am referenceing the managedDTS and DTSruntimewrapper ( dlls from memory as I am away from the server at the moment). I have to ensure that 
I use the .net 4.o framework ( not client).

So my question is that : is there a particular order/method/process I need to use to configure be able to use the configuration above? I have successfully created simple packages that have containers and vairables that work successfully
. The problem appears to be with data flow and tasks.

Any guidance is much appreaciateed. Should I regress back to SQL 2008 R2 instead of 2012 for example...

Many thanks.
Richard

Comment: Did you check the release notes of the ezAPI.dll you downloaded with your SQL Server version? Not all versions of ezAPI are stable. If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, the last stable changeset is 65381 according to the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulrizza/archive/2013/06/02/entry-2-ssis-intro-to-ezapi.aspx

Comment: Many thanks Frank, I've got a feeling I've got the dec 12 2010 build which think about probably isn't compatible with 2012 SQl server..? I'm a bit slow but the latest ezAPI entry says 2012 but no downloads. Do you know if there is one available. I tries to build the dll from code but got in a mess with getting the correct GAC libraries. Have you used ezAPI with 2012 and if so how ? Richard

Comment: Bill much appreciate any light you can through on this. Your blog has been invaluable.. Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so Frank was onto the issue, the version of ezAPI I was using was not compatible with SQL server 2012, so the error is a useful sign of this compatibility issue.

So you need to build a 2012 from scratch.

To create a compatible version for 2012  you have to follow the following steps:

1/ download the code from codeplex library
Navigate to  (http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/82369)
Click on the  change set 86517 link (http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/86517)
then download the code and c# project file

2/ Build the project. You might find issues with libraries, there is a helpful question Bill answered ([VSTAScriptingLib for SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854103/vstascriptinglib-for-sql-server-2012?rq=1))
This now works and I have successfully managed to create and run dataflow tasks.

Thank you for putting me on the right track.

Very pleased.  Richard